# Slower delete from smaller parent table

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my application I'm deleting from a child and then a parent table, in a PostgreSQL database. I'm deleting in the following order:

```
DELETE FROM answers_reports_t WHERE event_reports_id in (
                    SELECT id FROM events_reports_t WHERE recall_id = :recallId)"

DELETE FROM events_reports_t WHERE recall_id = :recallId
```

The table `answers_reports_t` is a child table whose foreign key `event_reports_id` references the parent table's `events_reports_t.id`.

Multiple Answers belong to an Event and the size ratio is ~3:1. Currently, `answers_reports_t` has 280K rows and `events_reports_t` 95K.

I'm noticing that delete #2 is consistently slower than delete #1, even though the difference is tiny. This is from the app's log.

```
ANSWERS Delete: 41ms
EVENTS  Delete: 58ms
ANSWERS Delete: 41ms
EVENTS  Delete: 59ms
ANSWERS Delete: 41ms
EVENTS  Delete: 67ms
```

The indexes are in place as below.

[image]

I was expecting the opposite for performance. Also, is it possible to somehow combine this Parent-Child Delete, for further performance optimization?

Comment: Have you tried `ON DELETE CASCADE`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're avoiding cascading constraints? For example, see [Delete rows and other rows with a reference to the deleted row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59944951/delete-rows-and-other-rows-with-a-reference-to-the-deleted-row). The constraint is probably also why it's slower, because the delete on the parent table must check the dependent tables.

Comment: Thanks will give it a try. `CASCADE` has a dangerous reputation and I've been told to use it sparingly.

Comment: Check the output of `explain (analyze) delete ...` I wouldn't be surprised if the FK checking is slow due to missing indexes.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, is it possible to somehow combine this Parent-Child Delete, for further performance optimization?

Yes, it's possible to do this in a single statement using a [data-modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING), but I doubt it's substantially faster

```
with report_delete as (
   DELETE FROM events_reports_t 
   WHERE recall_id = 2
   returning id
)
DELETE FROM answers_reports_t 
WHERE event_reports_id in (select id from report_delete);
```